# Shell pattern matching and arithmetic operators (+ - * / %)

Tags: bash, regular-expression, patterns

This looks so simple but it isn't:

`[[ "1234+5678" =~ [0-9]+(\s*(\-|\*)\s*[0-9]+)* ]] && echo $?`

returns a `0`. However, it actually should not do that, as only minus (`-`) and multiplication (`*`) operator are allowed.
Also, I grabbed some regex tool in the net and tried to match this pattern: result was the null string. (as expected)

In prose, this *extended* regex reads:

- look for number (mandatory)
- check if there is some white space
- operator must be either a `-` or a `*`
- check if there is some white space (again)
- look for another number (must be there if preceded by an operator)

Also, the asterisk following the expression in parentheses says that 2nd to nth operator-number pair is optional.

Where is my mistake in thinking here?

Answer (score 3):

Without markers the regexp (right part) can ***match any part*** of string. So your variant match `1234`.
To satisfy requirements you have to use markers:

```
[[ "1234+5678" =~ ^[0-9]+(\s*(\-|\*)\s*[0-9]+)*$ ]] ; echo $?
```

And shorter (if you'd like):

```
[[ "1234+5678" =~ ^[0-9\ *-]+*$ ]] ; echo $?
```

Comment: SO simple? Just putting the `^` at the beginning did the trick. Thank you very much! (also for *not* inverting the logic for no reason ;)) Again: single numbers must work as well as numbers with addends. So it is not that simple as replacing `*` by `+`.

Comment: the shorter expression also matches `123-*5*`

Comment: Note that `\s*` stands for various whitespace like e. g. tabulators as well. Your shorter solution blindly assumes that whitespace = space, which is a little naughty ;) Plus, whatever you write into `[ ]` is *arbitrary in order*, whilst my expression dictates a definite order - for a reason! Your expression would even allow a `*` or `-` as first characters, which is plainly wrong, as they are arithmetic operators and __must__ be preceded by a number. Shorter is not always better, as it may unwantedly alter the logic.

Comment: @ikrabbe Yes, but the choice to use (or do not use) some variant or its modification depends of operated data and users forecast.

Comment: @syntaxerror I have stated: `if you'd like`. Certainly, if you expect data with `a * or - as first characters` and so on you are free to choice 1 variant but in most cases shorter is enough

Comment: It's in fact the other way round. I DO NOT expect data with `*` or `-` as first character, but the shorter expression will allow this (and I can't permit that ;)) IOW, the shorter one is too liberal and data which should be filtered out will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression returns 0 because it matches the first number.  Anchor the regexp to make it do what you want:

```
[[ "1234+5678" =~ ^[0-9]+( *(-|\*) *[0-9]+)*$ ]] && echo $?
```

On a side note: (1) you don't need to quote `-`, and (2) `\s` is not recognized as an ERE.

Comment: Thanks, also for the info about `\s`. Well, I wanted to support both tabulators (et al.) and "plain" spaces, hence I used `\s` on purpose. However, I wasn't aware that this is not part of ERE. Most peculiar...

Comment: It isn't peculiar: `\s` and friends come from Perl's lineage of regexps, not the much older BRE / ERE.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[ "1234+5678" =~ [0-9]+(\s*(\-|\*)\s*[0-9]+) ]] ; echo $?
```

The `*` regex operator at the end of your regex allows any number of repeats of the expression inside the () also none. So you match [0-9]+ from the start and the rest is optional.

If you remove the `*` or replace it by a `+` the expression returns as expected.

> Also, the asterisk following the expression in parentheses says that
>   2nd to nth operator-number pair is optional.

That is the mistake: The `*` means the any operator is option. Use the `+` operator!

Ok, that was not the answer, but you can consume the expressions and see if the result is empty:

```
echo "1234*5678"|sed 's/[0-9]\+\([ \*\-][0-9]\+\)*//'
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's meant to be that way. :) It should match on "1234" *as well as* "2345*6789*4321", or in prose, on single numbers as well as on "formulae" (i. e. additions in this case). However, the problem is that it matches also on additions `+` and divisions `/`, even though I'm only allowing subtractions and multiplications in this sample one-liner. Your answer will also exclude standalone numbers, as now you do no longer allow that the addend be omitted.

Comment: Just add an end anchor (`$`) and you are set: `[[ "1234+5678" =~ [0-9]+(\s*(\-|\*)\s*[0-9]+)*$ ]] || echo $?`

Comment: @ user1794469 No. Doesn't help me at all. By replacing `&&` by `||`, you've just inverted the logic. Coolish. But that's totally pointless, as I need the result of the expression itself, not the result if the expression is false.

Comment: I thought so, but it doesn't work, I inverted the logic just to get some output from a expression that is true.

Comment: @ikrabbe It definitely doesn't. :) So I now get it, you were the initiator of inverting the logic, and user179... just jumped on the bandwagon. LOL.

Comment: "but you can consume the expressions and see if the result is empty" * GASP * Eh? That `sed` approach is a dirty hack. As Costas shows in the other answer, it *can* be done with pattern matching - there was just a tiny nudge into the right direction that I was missing. :)

Comment: yes I now know that Costas answer is the right answer to what you initally wanted, but the sed expression is simpler to debug as you see what happens. I wouldn't call that sed approach too dirty and you are shell agnostic with that.